# htaccess autodetect absolute path

Tags: .htaccess

I am trying to make a 404 redirect in a subdirectory on my server. Ex https://website.com/subdirectory/ when a user enters an incorrect url.

Can I determine the absolute path to this subdirectory using htaccess?

I tried:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /server/404.shtml [R=301,L]
```

so my 404.shtml resides in public_html/website/subdirectory/server/ meaning it's not directly in the root directory.

Or is there something like RQUEST_URI (some sort of a reques_path) but show the path up to the filename?

Comment: Why do you have to "detect" it at runtime? You _know_ that path. So just use it in your directive. Alternatively you can setup an alias: `Alias /404 /path/to/that/404.shtml`.

Comment: If I put the file in another subdirectory I would have to rename the path. My intention is to make this path relative. Or at least determine the URL that leads to that specific new subdirectory using only htaccess.

Comment: Sorry, but that makes little sense. How should some logic "detect" what folder or file you might be referring to if not by it's location? A global error document is an absolute resource. You do not want to move it around, what for? And if you really, why ever, need such a highly dynamic setup, then use a router script for such resources.

Comment: In this particular situation, I want to make the standard HTML errors work for a script the user will apply in his project. I would have liked the user to skip the step where he has to alter the htaccess file to point out the exact path where the 400, 404, etc files are on his server if he is not placing them in the public_html root folder.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't get it. What sense is there in allowing the use of an arbitrary path if you then have to guess it again? This goes round in circles without offering any benefit. But I do not have to understand this. I just recommend not to invest time into such a "feature" which only confuses and reduces robustness without offering anything not available otherwise.

Comment: I see. yeah, I guess it's not worth the trouble for one simple path that the user can input himself afteral.